# continuity of derivative of continuous functions differentiable everywhere

Tags: derivatives, continuity

For a continuous function if derivative exists everywhere is it necessary that the derivative itself is continuous. I am unable to think of any counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ if $x \neq 0, f(0) =0$

Here we have

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h^2 \sin(1/h)-0}{h}= 0,$$

but

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} [2x \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)]$$

does not exist.

Comment: That is the classical example!  +1  And it is so elegant and illuminating to students who initially might struggle with the idea that existence of a derivative does not imply its continuity.